# Excel conditionally format a row based on a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table something like this:

```
text1A | text2A | value1A | text3A | value2A
text1B | text2B | value1B | text3B | value2B
text1C | text2C | value1C | text3C | value2C
```

If the value in column 3 is larger than the previous value, I would like the whole row to have a bottom border.

If the value in column 3 is smaller than the previous value, I would like the whole row to have a **bold** bottom border.

If the value in column 3 is equal, do nothing.

Anyone know how to do this with Excel conditional formating?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative references in Conditional Formatting conditions.

1. Highlight the whole table.
2. Click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Under Format values where this formula is true, type `=$C1<$C2`
4. Click Format > Border. Set the bottom border, then click OK.
5. Click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format
6. Under Format values where this formula is true, type `=$C2<$C1`
7. Click Format > Font > Font Style = Bold. Then click OK.